# Convert LEFT OUTER JOIN to only use subqueries and annotations

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to convert a LEFT OUTER JOIN to use only queries and subqueries with annotations?

I have a complex query like this that I cannot use LEFT OUTER JOINS and need to somehow do without:

```
select count(cua.a),cua.b, w.c, cp.p
from cua
LEFT OUTER JOIN cp on cp.id=cua.b
JOIN cu on cu.id=cua.a
LEFT OUTER JOIN w on w.id = cu.w_id
where cp.id=1
and (date IS NULL or date > NOW())
group by cua.b, cp.p, w.c, w.name;
```

If I can just figure out how to do left outer joins with subqueries and other function then I think I can figure out the whole thing.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

EDIT: added table names (X.y)

Comment: Qualify all the column names with the table name/alias they belong.

Comment: Why can you not use left outer joins? Is there anything else you cannot use?

Comment: In what direction do your foreign key constraints point?

Comment: @forpas, I added the table names to the names.

Comment: `group by ... w.name`? Why would you group by a column you don't select? `count(cua.a)`? So, `cua.a` is nullable and you only want to count non-null occurrences? Why then `JOIN cu on cu.id=cua.a` where you would dismiss all null occurences? And do you really want to outer join `cp` with ID 1? Or do you want to restrict your results to `cp.id = 1`. If the former, then move the condition to the `ON` clause, if the latter, then make this an inner join. What table does `date` reside in by the way? At last: It would help, did you show sample data, so we could see what you are trying to count.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
where cp.id=1
```

filters the results of your query in such a way that all the unmatched rows of the table `cp` are rejected, so:

```
LEFT JOIN cp
```

is equivalent to:

```
INNER JOIN cp
```

Also this:

```
group by cua.b, cp.p, w.c, w.name
```

uses 2 columns of the table `w`, so unless you want groups with `null`s for these 2 columns, this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN w
```

is equivalent to:

```
INNER JOIN w
```

So I guess there is no need for subqueries because you can rewrite safely your query with only `INNER` joins:

```
SELECT count(cua.a),cua.b, w.c, cp.p
FROM cua
INNER JOIN cp ON cp.id=cua.b
INNER JOIN cu ON cu.id=cua.a
INNER JOIN w ON w.id = cu.w_id
WHERE cp.id=1
AND (date IS NULL OR date > NOW())
GROUP BY cua.b, cp.p, w.c, w.name;
```

Comment: I need the nulls!

Comment: Then you need `LEFT JOIN w`